# sql server 2005 problem - defrag necessary?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, nhibernate

I insert some data into a sql server 2005 database using NHibernate. Before I insert an object I check whether it already exists based on its primary key. Every 100000 or so lookups this seems to throw some exception (if I do the same via sql it takes ages as well). A defragmentation of the hard disk seems to help but seems a bit strange that I have to do this - or is this normal?

BTW I know that I could use bulk insert but had to opt for NHibernate for certain reasons ...

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: The SQL error would really help.

Comment: I just get a time out exception in my c# code.

Comment: Sounds like a locking problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely to be database file growth if it's 100k inserts. Do you:

- shrink the database at all?
- have large growth increment?
- not have instant file initialisation enabled?

Defragging the filesystem is only useful for generating IO time-outs

Comment: Kimberly L. Tripp has an excellent article on instant file initialization [here](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Instant-Initialization-What-Why-and-How.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very likely that the time out you are seeing is due to database file growth. That would explain the consistent frequency of the slowness. I am not sure how frequently this occurs or the long term plan for the table. However, you may wish to manually grow the file to a much larger size to avoid the frequent overhead of the automatic growth.